# WPF Update UI Before Performing Other Operations

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I'm using WPF, Caliburn.Micro and WPF Extended Toolkit to display a busy indicator when I change the view that is displaying.  The issue is that the busy indicator never displays between the views being switched (which is why I need it).

**How It Works While Broken**

1. Click menu item
2. Set IsBusy = true
3. No busy indicator shows up
4. Change view (ChangeActiveItem(ViewModel, bool))
5. View displays
6. Busy indicator displays

**How It Should Work**

1. Click menu item
2. Set IsBusy = true
3. Busy Indicator displays
4. Change view
5. View Displays and renders fully
6. IsBusy = false
7. BusyIndicator hides

**ShellView (BusyIndicator Snippet)**

```
<xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}">
    <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" />
</xctk:BusyIndicator>
```

**NavigationViewModel (Method - Fires when clicking a menu item)**

```
public void NavigationItemClicked(NavigationItem item)
{
    _eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread(new NavigationItemClicked(item.ViewModelType));
}
```

**ShellViewModel (Method - Catches message from NavigationViewModel.NavigationItemClicked)**

```
public void Handle(NavigationItemClicked message)
{
    worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
    {
        ChangeActiveItem(QuestDetails, true);
        IsBusy = false;
    };

    IsBusy = true;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

**Also Tried**

1. Changing 'PublishOnUiThread' to 'PublishOnBackgroundThread'
2. Ayyappan Subramanian suggestion

Comment: I think you should try worker.RunWorkerAsync(); IsBusy = true;

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

- change isBusy status in runworkercompleted
- make isbusy public property
- in page constructor add datacontext
- IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"

  ```
  public void Handle(NavigationItemClicked message)
   {
   worker = new BackgroundWorker();

   worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
    {
      ChangeActiveItem(QuestDetails, true);
  IsBusy = false;
  };
   worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
   {

    IsBusy = true;
   };

   worker.RunWorkerAsync();
  }
  ```

Comment: Wouldn't this set IsBusy to true after the view changes?  Making the `BusyIndicator` never hide.

Comment: I've tried creating two workers.  One for `IsBusy = True` and one for `ChangeActiveItem()`.  I called the IsBusy worker first and ran the ChangeActiveItem worker inside of the IsBusy workers `RunWorkerCompleted`.  This did not work.